# String comparison function (c++)

Tags: c++

I am looking for a function to compare the two strings. A functional similar to strcmp in CString with the difference that takes two strands in the input.

Comment: strands? What string type are you using? What's wrong with `==` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use std::string::compare (it returns 0 if values are the same). Also be aware that in fact you can use strcmp in c++, but if you want modern c++ version i would go with std::string::compare.